# Creating an abstraction for two similar methods which have linq methods

Tags: c#, linq, dry

I have two methods which are very close, and want to create one method that I can call to keep my code DRY

```
public IEnumerable<HighScoreViewModel> GetNightlyHighScores()
{
    lock (_Key)
    {
        //return GetHighScores(x => x.NightlyHighScore);

        return _allPlayers
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.NightlyHighScore)
            .Take(8)
            .Select(x=> new HighScoreViewModel
            {
                Points = x.NightlyHighScore,
                PointsText = "FG: " + x.NightlyHighScore,
                ImageUrl = x.Facebook.SmallImageUrl,
                DisplayName = x.DisplayName,
            }).ToList();
    }
}

public IEnumerable<HighScoreViewModel> GetBestHighScores()
{
    lock (_Key)
    {
        //return GetHighScores(x => x.BestHighScore);

        return _allPlayers
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.BestHighScore)
            .Take(8)
            .Select(x => new HighScoreViewModel
            {
                Points = x.BestHighScore,
                PointsText = "FG: " + x.BestHighScore,
                ImageUrl = x.Facebook.SmallImageUrl,
                DisplayName = x.DisplayName,
            }).ToList();
    }
}
```

I'm close to something, but can't figure out the bits marked "magic"

```
public IEnumerable<HighScoreViewModel> GetHighScores<TKey>(Func<Player, TKey> highscore)
{
    return _allPlayers
        .OrderByDescending(highscore)
        .Take(8)
        .Select(x => new HighScoreViewModel
        {
            // Magic?
            //Points = x.BestHighScore,
            PointsText = "FG: " + x.BestHighScore,
            //ImageUrl = x.Facebook.SmallImageUrl,
            DisplayName = x.DisplayName,
        }).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `BestHighScore` and `NightlyHighScore` have the same type, you should be able to do:

```
public IEnumerable<HighScoreViewModel> GetHighScores(Func<Player, double> highscore)
{
    return _allPlayers
        .OrderByDescending(highscore)
        .Take(8)
        .Select(x => new HighScoreViewModel
        {
            // Magic?
            Points = highScore(x),
            PointsText = "FG: " + x.BestHighScore,
            //ImageUrl = x.Facebook.SmallImageUrl,
            DisplayName = x.DisplayName,
        }).ToList();
}
```

`highscore` should return whatever the real type of `Points` is.

Answer (score 1):

Not so magic, just use the function to get the value from the player:

```
public IEnumerable<HighScoreViewModel> GetHighScores<TKey>(Func<Player, TKey> highscore)
{
  return _allPlayers
    .OrderByDescending(highscore)
    .Take(8)
    .Select(x => new HighScoreViewModel
    {
        Points = highscore(x),
        PointsText = "FG: " + highscore(x),
        ImageUrl = x.Facebook.SmallImageUrl,
        DisplayName = x.DisplayName,
    }).ToList();
}
```

Call with:

```
GetHighScores(x => x.NightlyHighScore)
```

and

```
GetHighScores(x => x.BestHighScore)
```

Comment: I don't think this will compile - there's no conversion from `TKey` to the typeof `Points`.